# Calling a method within the superclass while instantiating a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an abstract class that several classes inherit from with attributes `health` and `damageTaken`, and within it there's a method called `takeDamage()`. Here's what it does:

```
public double takeDamage(int damage) {
   if(health <= 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   
   damageTaken += damage;
   health -= damage;
   
   return health;
}
```

Since several classes `extend` the class, I'm trying to get the class `Zombie` to be instantiated and call the `takeDamage()` in a `Test` class. Here's my code for that:

```
Zombie rob = new Zombie(100, 12, 3.4, 16, true, 500, "Sample Description");
rob.takeDamage(15);
```

When I try to call `takeDamage()`, I get a "cannot resolve symbol" error. I don't want to override `takeDamage()` in every single class this inherits from, instead I want the superclass' methods to be able to be called when instantiating a subclass. Any way to do that?

Comment: is zombie really an extension of class having `takeDamage` method??:>

Comment: yep, my class declaration is:

`public class Zombie extends Character { 

//code

}
`

Comment: And i dont see code the code for  the `Character`

Comment: `Character` is the one with `takeDamage` in it, there's a bunch more stuff in there so I just put in a placeholder for the actual code

Comment: Sorry, not seeing it at all. You need to include whole relevant code.

Comment: The relevant code is the `takeDamage` and Zombie instantiation that I put in the question, I can’t copy it in the comment due to the character limit.

Comment: The relevant code is the definition of zombie and whetever is in the class treee. To me, code for `takeDamage` is irrelevant, since I am only interested into its signature, not the body.

Comment: All zombie has is its constructor that has `super(damageTaken, health)` and a few more attributes in it